# How do i search in a String for a multiple word

Tags: java, string

I have a string like "UUDUUUUUUUUDU" and i want to find if the string has multiple UUDU in it. It is for a permutation programm. I tried with a matcher but the matcher reacts by a single UUDU and a multiple

```java
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("UUDU|UUDU").matcher(uudu);
    if(matcher.find())
    {
```

Comment: This should help: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_occurrences_of_a_substring#Java

Comment: What's the point of your pattern ? It is exactly equivalent to `"UUDU"`

Comment: Should overlapping matches be considered ? For example, for the string `UUUU`, should we count 2 or 3 matches of  `UU` ?.

Comment: it should count 2 matches thanks for all of your help i think I use the common library from apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using an external library, the Apache Commons StringUtils class provides the method [`CountMatches`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use group matching, pay attention - the `if` should be replaced with a `while`:

```
String uudu = "UUDUUUUUUUUDU";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(UUDU)").matcher(uudu);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
UUDU
UUDU
```

In order to count ***overlapping sub-strings***, we can do:

```
public static int countOverlappingSubstr(String subStr, String str, int i, int count){
    int subLen =  subStr.length();
    if (i >= str.length() - subLen + 1)
        return count;
    if (str.substring(i, i + subLen).equals(subStr))
        count++;
    return countOverlappingSubstr(subStr, str, i+1, count);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(countOverlappingSubstr("UUDU", "UUDUUDU", 0, 0));
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about that, but it does not take overlappoing matches into account

Comment: @Dici that wasn't the question - if you want you can post a new one ;)

Comment: That's why regex are not the answer, if the OP wants to take them into account, which is still unclear.

Comment: Good to have a tail-recursive solution :) Couldn't you improve it a bit by avoiding to create new strings with `String.substring` ? Might make a big difference for large strings. Your stopping condition seems suspicious. Are you sure it will always terminate ?

Comment: @Dici with valid input (a substring that is shorter than `str`) it will end. But yes, you got a point - fixed ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need to take overlapping matches into account, here is one solution. Otherwise, use alfasin solution, which is more straightforward.

```
private static int countOverlappingMatches(String str, String pattern) {
    int count  = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    while (str.length() > 0) {
        int i = str.indexOf(pattern,offset);
        if (i == -1) break;
        count++;
        offset = i + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```